# wordpress plugin to manage the layout/design of a theme

Tags: plugins

I want to use a plugin that will allow me to manage the layout/design of a wordpress site. Is there such a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

There are some projects around with such functionality:

- [Carrington Build](http://crowdfavorite.com/wordpress/carrington-build/)
- [Platform Pro](http://www.pagelines.com/themes/platformpro/)
- [Headway](http://headwaythemes.com/)
- and more...

But in general such functionality is on built-in or deep-integration-required level. It is simply too complex to be a generic plugin.